# Consequence of singular weight matrices in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, references, weights, singular-matrix

I want to know the effects of weight matrices being singular when using neural networks. Is there any supported literature? 
For non-square weights matrices, I am concerned about lower rank matrices.

Thanks.